# Why is my json file not nesting according to my depth parameter?

Tags: python, json, for-loop, nested-loops

I am doing a small code to fetch files in a folder and get the path into a json.

```
def main(directory_path):
    submodules, depth = parse_directory(directory_path)
    output = {
        "name": os.path.basename(directory_path),
        "repository": os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(directory_path)),
        "submodules": submodules
    }
    for i in range(len(submodules)):
        with open("output.json", "w") as output_file:
            json.dump(output, output_file, indent=depth[i]*4)
```

*NB: parse_directory is an other function I made to locate the file in the folder. It returns `submodules`, a list of parameters, and `depth`, a list of steps my parse does to go fetch the file.*

> i.e:  'path/to/file' is 3 steps, 'path/file' is 2 steps.

So I tried to do a for loop but my indent are always the same even thought my values in `depth` are changing according to the deep of the file in the folder. As you can see in the following example, indent is not recursive.

```
{
        "project": "the lion king",
        "repository": "C:\\Users\\path\\to\\folder",
        "submodules": [
                {
                        "name": "mufasa",
                        "path": "example\\mufasa",
                },
                {
                        "name": "simba",
                        "path": "example\\mufasa\\simba",
                },
                {
                        "name": "nala",
                        "path": "example\\nala",
                }
        ]
}
```

What I want is:

```
{
        "project": "the lion king",
        "repository": "C:\\Users\\path\\to\\folder",
        "submodules": [
                {
                        "name": "mufasa",
                        "path": "example\\mufasa",
                },
                        {
                                "name": "simba",
                                "path": "example\\mufasa\\simba",
                        },
                {
                        "name": "nala",
                        "path": "example\\nala",
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: You are completely rewriting your JSON file on every iteration of your `for` loop.  The only depth value that matters is the one used for the final iteration.

Comment: oh, I see. Is it possible to do indent variation then?@jasonharper

Comment: Not using the standard JSON tools, as any parameters affect the entire file.

Comment: Aside: Shouldn't `"name": os.path.basename(directory_path),` be `"project": os.path.basename(directory_path),`?

Comment: What's the point of the loop? Why are you iterating over the length of a dictionary?

Comment: I use the loop because each time a new file is found, the depth might be differend, so I need to indent proportionaly. it was a try to understand how my file was created @Barmar

Comment: But you're not looping over anything related to depth. It seems like the iteration should be related to `submodules`.

Comment: Or maybe `for curdepth in depth:`

Comment: Of course, this iteration doesn't help with your actual goal, since the value of `output` doesn't change.

Comment: yes I did change to submodules but even though that does not work... the fact is I need to access my submodules.path of "submodules" to get the depth variation.@Barmar